# Edge manipulation detection in fullscreen mode is not working as expected in UWP app

Tags: winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I have a situation where manipulation events emanating from offscreen (think bezel of surface pro) are not being registered when the app is in fullscreen mode. However, they are registering as expected when the application is "maximized" (I put that in quotes because I know it's no longer officially a "thing" to be maximized).

To reproduce, create the blank application and add the code at the end of this post.

Swipe from top down, and notice an absence of any manipulation events being fired. Now click the exit full screen button then the maximize button and repeat the experiment, and you will see that manipulation events now properly fire.

It is important to start dragging offscreen.

Is this by design? Is there a gotcha that I'm not aware of? Is it a bug?

The following Xaml file:

```
<Page
x:Class="EdgeSwipeDetect.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:EdgeSwipeDetect"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="Green"
      ManipulationMode="TranslateInertia,TranslateY"
      ManipulationStarted="Grid_ManipulationStarted"
      ManipulationCompleted="Grid_ManipulationCompleted"
      ManipulationDelta="Grid_ManipulationDelta" />

</Page>
```

Code behind:

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        CoreApplicationViewTitleBar coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
        coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;

        var appView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
        appView.TryEnterFullScreenMode();
    }

    private void Grid_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ManipulationStarted");
    }

    private void Grid_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ManipulationCompleted");
    }

    private void Grid_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ManipulationDelta");
    }
}
```

Comment: Tested your code, it works fine by my side both on local machine and mobile emulator when the app is in full screen mode. OS version is 10586.

Comment: That's interesting. I have 10586 too. I'm going to put this issue on ice for now while I move on to other issues with the assumption that it's a local problem with my setup.  I will revisit the question in a few weeks. Thank you for taking the time to check it.